# Retrieve data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a database with columns Email, FirstName, LastName, Password.. etc
My login page uses email and password for logging in
I want to retrieve the name typed in LastName column in the same row as Email
I would like to know how to do so
My code looks like this:-

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$email' AND 
`password`='$encrypted_pass' ");
```

After this, I want to be able to assign a variable to the LastName so I could create a session along with login

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I suggest that you need a good tutorial.  That might be a website, perhaps one found by Googling "php mysql tutorial", or a good book.  Your local public library probably has a number of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this covers everything you asked for.  Starts a session, checks if it is good, setup a couple of variables for our post data, do some data validation, setup the query, query the db, check results, set var lastname in session.

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: text/html');

    session_start();
    if (session_id() === '') {
        echo 'session_id is null!';
        exit;
    }   
    $myemail = null;
    $mypassword = null;

    if (isset($_POST['Submit']) == true) {
        //assuming you have a db connection
        //mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) || die(mysql_error());
        //mysql_select_db($database) || die(mysql_error()); 

    if ((isset($_POST["username"]) === false)||
            (isset($_POST["password"]) === false)) {
            echo 'Please fill in all fields';
            exit;
        } else {
            // get the post data
            $myemail = ($_POST["username"]);
            $mypassword = ($_POST["password"]);
        }

    // check the form in database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = '".$myemail."' 
            AND password = '".$mypassword."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
    if ($count === 1) {
        $userrecord = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userrecord['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $userrecord['password'];
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $userrecord['lastname']; 
        // assign last name to a session var

        echo 'You have been logged in successfully";
    } else {
         echo 'Wrong username or password';
         exit;
    }
} else {
    echo "No form post detected.<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Here's some basic stuff using Mysqli since mysql_ commands are deprecated.  Again, it uses some common names so adjust accordingly.

```
    /********************************/
    // using mysqli (untested but should work)
    /********************************/

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword", "default_dbname");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // ecsape the query params
    $myemail = $mysqli->real_escape_string($myemail);
    $mypassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string($mypassword);

    if ($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = '$myemail' 
                        AND password = '$mypassword'")) {
        printf("%d Rows returned.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

    // here is where you can set the $_SESSION vars
    // and do any other work you want to do on login.

    }


    $mysqli->close();
    /********************************/
    //end mysqli
    /********************************/
```

One last thing.  Get yourself a GitHub.com repository setup so you can easily rollback to a prior version.  It really is a must have IMO.

Comment: array(3) { ["name"]=> NULL ["lastname"]=> NULL ["logged_in"]=> string(9) "logged in" } You have been logged in successfully
I tried the this one --> if($count===1){
 $userrecord = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 session_start();
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $userrecord['lastname']; 
 $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'logged in';
 var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo 'You have been logged in successfully';
}

Comment: I left a var_dump in there oops.  This is sample code that used common values for the names in the query, etc., did you check if everything was correct?  The array values are null because there was nothing returned from the query (if it actually ran). There's no need to move the session_start or any other parts of the code around to try this or that.  The code works if you have the form posting properly and the names I used are correct.  I commented in the code regarding your database connection and assumed you had a connection open, do you?

Comment: Worked.. thankyou! can I have your email so I can ask you help when I get into trouble? I am a novice 14 year old

Comment: I am glad it worked.  Now scrap part of it and start looking into current development methods using [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  The **mysql_** functions have been deprecated and should no longer be used. Welcome to development :) Look at Mysqli, with you being new to everything would probably be a little easier to grasp.  I'm honored you would request my help but ask your question(s) here so everyone can benefit from the answers.  I spend a lot of time on SQL tag so you'll often see me there.

Comment: Asking questions has been banned from my account xD

Answer (score 1):

Then you specify the column in the column list:

```
SELECT LastName
FROM Users
WHERE email = '$email'
...
```

You then need fetch the result set to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_ functions are officially deprecated and no longer maintained/safe to use.

You should use PHP's PDO instead as it is a safer and more object-oriented approach.
Just fill in DB_NAME, DB_USER_NAME, and DB_USER_PASS with your specific credentials and this code should work for you.

```
$database = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=UTF-8', 'DB_USER_NAME', 'DB_USER_PASS' );

$query = $database->prepare( "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ? " );
$query->bindValue( 1, $email );
$query->bindValue( 2, $encrypted_pass );
$query->execute();

if( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query

    $result = $query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    echo $result[ 'LastName' ]; # <-- The LastName field you were looking for!

}
else { echo "No Rows Returned!"; }
```

For more information of PHP PDO, please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php